# Customer Impact and Y-axis exaggerations

Tags: r, self-study

I'm working with a fictional pizza company to investigate a drop in on-time deliveries. It would be helpful to know if the statistical conclusion is correct here.

Each day, a rolling-28day percent of on-time deliveries is calculated. This is the ratio of `sum_delivered_ontime_past28d / sum_all_deliveries_past28d`.

[image]

The changes on the chart look dramatic enough to scare executives.

But this only impacts 66 customers. Here's how that impact is calculated: We focus on two dates, the Aug highpoint on the 31st (88.83% ontime), and the most recent data point Sept 24 (88.16%). To get the exact customer impact, we add up the total number of deliveries on Aug 31 and 28 days prior. We also do the same for the end of September. We match the most recent September deliveries to the Aug highpoint ontime rate, to get a perfect world scenario with no drop. Then find the difference between this perfect world outcome and the real outcome.

```
deliveries_at_aug_highpoint <- 8300 
aug_highest_ontime_pct <- .8883

deliveries_at_sep_low <- 9900
sep_lowest_ontime_pct <- .8816

sep_ontime_deliveries <- deliveries_at_sep_low * sep_lowest_ontime_pct

#In a world where there was no drop in ontime pct
nodrop_ontime <- deliveries_at_sep_low * aug_highest_ontime_pct
cust_impact <- round(nodrop_ontime - sep_ontime_deliveries)
[1] 66
```

Is this math sound? Are the executives falling prey to the y-axis effect of small differences in percentages "looking" worse than they are?

Comment: Please explain what that chart represents and how it does so--without such a description, it could mean thousands of different things to thousands of different readers, all but one of which will therefore misunderstand it.

Comment: I've added more on the x and y axis for clarity. The daily percent of all deliveries that were on-time over 3 months

Comment: Thank you.  The improved chart is intriguing by providing context.  But as far as your question goes, it sounds like a matter of business practice, not statistics.  Many executives might be horrified at the prospect of disappointing 66 customers, on the principle that for each disappointed one there will be ten times as many who feel negatively about the company, and 660 customers is such a sizable proportion of all customers that in a low-margin business they could represent the difference between profitability and ruin. Who are we to contend that's a "small" difference?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful summary. The statistics come in with advice on what is signal and what is noise. If the drop is a sign of something wrong than the co. should act, but if the fluctuation is within a range of variance, than an over-reaction can be negative.

Comment: The effect of seeing a zoomed-in chart can drive the company to make a decision based on a bias of the chart dimensions rather than fundamentals.